# Unable to get Key and Value in picklist in richfaces

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, converters, picklist

Hi I am new to richfaces picklist , My scenario is to load hashmap and by selecting the key value i need to load it in picklist. After getting the key i need to generate dynamic jasper report. My problem is while try to load the map value i end up with Typecast exception with the examples i came accross.

```
 <rich:pickList id="pickList1" value="#{xxx.selectionBean.fieldNameList}" sourceCaption="Fields to be Selected for Report"
                targetCaption="Selected Fields for Report" listWidth="165px" listHeight="100px" orderable="true" converter="pickListConvertor">
               <f:selectItems value="#{xxx.commencementworkBean.commencementList}" var="s"
                     itemLabel="#{s.key}" itemValue="#{s.value}" />
                      <f:converter converterId="pickListConvertor" />
          </rich:pickList>
```

**SelectionBean**

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SelectionBean  implements Serializable{

    /**
    vs00324258
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1597587007448113972L;
    private String key;
    private String value;

    List<SelectionBean> fieldNameList = new ArrayList<SelectionBean>();
    List<SelectionBean> dynamicList = new ArrayList<SelectionBean>();
    List<Object> fieldList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public List<SelectionBean> getFieldNameList() {
        return fieldNameList;
    }
    public void setFieldNameList(List<SelectionBean> fieldNameList) {
        this.fieldNameList = fieldNameList;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public List<SelectionBean> getDynamicList() {
        return dynamicList;
    }
    public void setDynamicList(List<SelectionBean> dynamicList) {
        this.dynamicList = dynamicList;
    }
    public List<Object> getFieldList() {
        return fieldList;
    }
    public void setFieldList(List<Object> fieldList) {
        this.fieldList = fieldList;
    }

}
```

**PicklistConvertor**

```
@FacesConverter(value = "pickListConvertor")
public class PickListConvertor implements Converter{

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if(submittedValue.trim().equals("")){
            return null;
        }else{
            return submittedValue.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
         if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
                return "";
            } else {
                return String.valueOf(((SelectionBean) value));
            }
    }

}
```

**CommencementWorkBean**

```
public class CommencementworkBean  implements Serializable{

    /**
     vs00324258 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5020735931910106047L;

    private String agreementnum;
    private String agreementtype;
    private String authorityentering;
    private String contractorname;
    private String tendercalledbyoffice;
    private Date dateofagreemtn;
    private Date dateofcommofwork;
    private Date dateofintendedcompl;
    private Date tenderdate;
    private Date duedateofmeterialworks;
    private Date regdateofcontract;
    private String detailsofsecurdeposit;
    private String estamtsanctionno;
    private String estimateamt;
    private String isitlowest;
    private String nameofwork;
    private String orignalorsupplemental;
    private String pricevariationapplicable;
    private String reasonforlowest;
    private String regnumberofvendor;
    private String remarks;
    private String taxes;
    private String statusCode;
    private String tenderauthority;
    private String tenderpremium;
    private String validityofsecurdeposit;
    private String valueofcontract;
    private String worldbankapproval;
    private boolean searchCommTableEnabled = false;
    private String fieldName;
    private Map<String,Object> commencementList = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
    private String headerName;
    private String valueName;
    private List<CommencementworkBean>searchCommencementBeanList = new ArrayList<CommencementworkBean>();
    public String getAgreementnum() {
        return agreementnum;
    }
    public void setAgreementnum(String agreementnum) {
        this.agreementnum = agreementnum;
    }
    public String getAgreementtype() {
        return agreementtype;
    }
    public void setAgreementtype(String agreementtype) {
        this.agreementtype = agreementtype;
    }
    public String getAuthorityentering() {
        return authorityentering;
    }
    public void setAuthorityentering(String authorityentering) {
        this.authorityentering = authorityentering;
    }
    public String getContractorname() {
        return contractorname;
    }
    public void setContractorname(String contractorname) {
        this.contractorname = contractorname;
    }
    public String getTendercalledbyoffice() {
        return tendercalledbyoffice;
    }
    public void setTendercalledbyoffice(String tendercalledbyoffice) {
        this.tendercalledbyoffice = tendercalledbyoffice;
    }
    public Date getDateofagreemtn() {
        return dateofagreemtn;
    }
    public void setDateofagreemtn(Date dateofagreemtn) {
        this.dateofagreemtn = dateofagreemtn;
    }
    public Date getDateofcommofwork() {
        return dateofcommofwork;
    }
    public void setDateofcommofwork(Date dateofcommofwork) {
        this.dateofcommofwork = dateofcommofwork;
    }
    public Date getDateofintendedcompl() {
        return dateofintendedcompl;
    }
    public void setDateofintendedcompl(Date dateofintendedcompl) {
        this.dateofintendedcompl = dateofintendedcompl;
    }
    public Date getTenderdate() {
        return tenderdate;
    }
    public void setTenderdate(Date tenderdate) {
        this.tenderdate = tenderdate;
    }
    public Date getRegdateofcontract() {
        return regdateofcontract;
    }
    public void setRegdateofcontract(Date regdateofcontract) {
        this.regdateofcontract = regdateofcontract;
    }
    public String getDetailsofsecurdeposit() {
        return detailsofsecurdeposit;
    }
    public void setDetailsofsecurdeposit(String detailsofsecurdeposit) {
        this.detailsofsecurdeposit = detailsofsecurdeposit;
    }
    public String getEstamtsanctionno() {
        return estamtsanctionno;
    }
    public void setEstamtsanctionno(String estamtsanctionno) {
        this.estamtsanctionno = estamtsanctionno;
    }
    public String getEstimateamt() {
        return estimateamt;
    }
    public void setEstimateamt(String estimateamt) {
        this.estimateamt = estimateamt;
    }
    public String getIsitlowest() {
        return isitlowest;
    }
    public void setIsitlowest(String isitlowest) {
        this.isitlowest = isitlowest;
    }
    public String getNameofwork() {
        return nameofwork;
    }
    public void setNameofwork(String nameofwork) {
        this.nameofwork = nameofwork;
    }
    public String getOrignalorsupplemental() {
        return orignalorsupplemental;
    }
    public void setOrignalorsupplemental(String orignalorsupplemental) {
        this.orignalorsupplemental = orignalorsupplemental;
    }
    public String getPricevariationapplicable() {
        return pricevariationapplicable;
    }
    public void setPricevariationapplicable(String pricevariationapplicable) {
        this.pricevariationapplicable = pricevariationapplicable;
    }
    public String getReasonforlowest() {
        return reasonforlowest;
    }
    public void setReasonforlowest(String reasonforlowest) {
        this.reasonforlowest = reasonforlowest;
    }
    public String getRegnumberofvendor() {
        return regnumberofvendor;
    }
    public void setRegnumberofvendor(String regnumberofvendor) {
        this.regnumberofvendor = regnumberofvendor;
    }
    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }
    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }
    public String getTaxes() {
        return taxes;
    }
    public void setTaxes(String taxes) {
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }
    public String getTenderauthority() {
        return tenderauthority;
    }
    public void setTenderauthority(String tenderauthority) {
        this.tenderauthority = tenderauthority;
    }
    public String getTenderpremium() {
        return tenderpremium;
    }
    public void setTenderpremium(String tenderpremium) {
        this.tenderpremium = tenderpremium;
    }
    public String getValidityofsecurdeposit() {
        return validityofsecurdeposit;
    }
    public void setValidityofsecurdeposit(String validityofsecurdeposit) {
        this.validityofsecurdeposit = validityofsecurdeposit;
    }
    public String getValueofcontract() {
        return valueofcontract;
    }
    public void setValueofcontract(String valueofcontract) {
        this.valueofcontract = valueofcontract;
    }
    public String getWorldbankapproval() {
        return worldbankapproval;
    }
    public void setWorldbankapproval(String worldbankapproval) {
        this.worldbankapproval = worldbankapproval;
    }
    public Date getDuedateofmeterialworks() {
        return duedateofmeterialworks;
    }
    public void setDuedateofmeterialworks(Date duedateofmeterialworks) {
        this.duedateofmeterialworks = duedateofmeterialworks;
    }
    public boolean isSearchCommTableEnabled() {
        return searchCommTableEnabled;
    }
    public void setSearchCommTableEnabled(boolean searchCommTableEnabled) {
        this.searchCommTableEnabled = searchCommTableEnabled;
    }
    public List<CommencementworkBean> getSearchCommencementBeanList() {
        return searchCommencementBeanList;
    }
    public void setSearchCommencementBeanList(
            List<CommencementworkBean> searchCommencementBeanList) {
        this.searchCommencementBeanList = searchCommencementBeanList;
    }
    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }
    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
    public String getHeaderName() {
        return headerName;
    }
    public void setHeaderName(String headerName) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }
    public String getValueName() {
        return valueName;
    }
    public void setValueName(String valueName) {
        this.valueName = valueName;
    }
    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getCommencementList() {
        return commencementList;
    }
    public void setCommencementList(Map<String, Object> commencementList) {
        this.commencementList = commencementList;
    }
}
```

What should i do to get key and value from the selection list.

**Exception**

```
 java.lang.String cannot be cast to xxx.xxx.xxx.bean.SelectionBean
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to  xxx.xxx.xxx.bean.SelectionBean
    at org.gov.tnwrd.utils.PickListConvertor.getAsString(PickListConvertor.java:26)
    at org.richfaces.component.util.InputUtils.getConvertedStringValue(InputUtils.java:96)
    at org.richfaces.component.util.InputUtils.getConvertedStringValue(InputUtils.java:88)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectHelper.generateClientSelectItem(SelectHelper.java:80)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectManyHelper.getClientSelectItems(SelectManyHelper.java:254)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectManyRendererBase.getClientSelectItems(SelectManyRendererBase.java:60)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PickListRenderer.encodeEnd(PickListRenderer.java:202)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:181)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl$RenderVisitCallback.visit(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:504)
    at org.richfaces.context.BaseExtendedVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(BaseExtendedVisitContext.java:321)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTogglePanel.visitTree(AbstractTogglePanel.java:743)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.processPartialRenderPhase(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:272)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: the stack suggests you're getting a `String` and not a `SelectionBean` when you do the cast in `getAsString`

Comment: Actually my requirement is i need to get the key and value from the hashmap and i was suggested to follow this http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList. How to get the key and value from picklist.

Comment: does `xxx.commencementworkBean.commencementList` correctly defines a list of `SelectionBean`?

Comment: No commencementList is the hashmap

Comment: `value` attribute of `f:selectItems` [must point](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/) at any `Collection` or `array`